# Google Nest E - incorrectly wired? (UK)

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I've just installed a Nest E in place of our old thermostat and it doesn't appear to be working correctly. The Nest E and the Heat Link both communicate with each other fine but when the power is switched on at the mains, the boiler doesn't power up.

I've attached a photo of the old thermostat and the Nest E wiring.

The old thermostat is an EPH RF1A-OT and the boiler is a Worcester Bosch Greenstar 4000.

[image: old]

[image: new]

I do have limited knowledge but having followed the guidance I believe everything seems correct (though guidance wasn't brilliant).

Have I wired it correctly?

Would really appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: No strain relief, and that's not a GND terminal! Switch off and call an electrician.

Comment: Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was a blown fuse within the boiler itself, no other issues with wiring.

Comment: No issues - apart from using the protective earth conductor as switched live, which is potentially hazardous!

Answer (score 0):

According to the installation manual:
https://nest.com/support/images/misc-nest-thermostat/nest-thermostat-e-install-guide.pdf, page 7:

> "High-voltage wires If your thermostat is labeled 120V or 240V,   or
> has thick wires with wire nuts, or has   L1 and L2 terminal blocks,
> your system   is high voltage and isn’t compatible with   the Nest
> Thermostat."

The NEST thermostats are compatible with 24V systems. You are connecting it to 230V (see the print on the thermostat next to the N sticker), so you will most likely damage the thermostat if you power it up like that.

Comment: This is for US systems.